# How to deal with emojis in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, emoji

I'm trying put some emojis in a text view. Most of the emojis are ok. I used [Emoji example from github](https://github.com/valeriomazzeo/NSString-Emoji). When I'm putting some emojis it's string look like (When I'm debugging),

[image]

```
-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    NSString *string = self.postTxtView.text;
    string = [string stringByReplacingEmojiCheatCodesWithUnicode];
    NSLog(@"%@", string);
    [self.postTxtView setText:string];
}
```

How may I avoid these question mark like box? How can I get a string like `:woman-heart-woman:`?

Comment: can you show your code ? what you tried ?

Comment: you also have to use - (NSString *)stringByReplacingEmojiCheatCodesWithUnicode; this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to perform encoding here.

Send your string like below to server.

```
NSData *data1 = [vTextView.text dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString  *nameSubject = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Retrieve your string as emojis like below.

```
NSData *dataRetrive = [response[@"key"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *goodValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataRetrive encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
```